# creating a table from plain text with multi line entries in r

Tags: r, read.table, readr

I have a PDF file with a table. I am using `pdftools::pdf_text` function to extract the text and I get a vector with several lines which represent the table.

My problem is, that there are only spaces and some cells have multiple lines. I am looking for a strategy to get this into a data frame. I played a bit with `data.table(text='')` but this is complaining about mismatching number of elements per row.

```
 Name                             Separator Description
 Protein IDs                                Identifier(s) of protein(s) contained in the protein group. They
                                            are sorted by number of identified peptides in descending
                                            order.
 Majority protein IDs                       These are the IDs of those proteins that have at least half of
                                            the peptides that the leading protein has.
 Peptide counts (all)                       Number of peptides associated with each protein in protein
                                            group, occuring in the order as the protein IDs occur in the
                                            'Protein IDs' column. Here distinct peptide sequences are
                                            counted. Modified forms or different charges are counted as
                                            one peptide.
```

Here is the data

```
my_lines <- c("     Name                             Separator Description", 
"    Protein IDs                                Identifier(s) of protein(s) contained in the protein group. They", 
"                                               are sorted by number of identified peptides in descending", 
"                                               order.", "    Majority protein IDs                       These are the IDs of those proteins that have at least half of", 
"                                               the peptides that the leading protein has.", 
"    Peptide counts (all)                       Number of peptides associated with each protein in protein", 
"                                               group, occuring in the order as the protein IDs occur in the", 
"                                               'Protein IDs' column. Here distinct peptide sequences are", 
"                                               counted. Modified forms or different charges are counted as", 
"                                               one peptide."
)
```

**EDIT:**
my expected Output would be a data frame like this:

```
                  Name Separator
1          Protein IDs          
2 Majority protein IDs          
3 Peptide counts (all)          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 Description
1                                                                                                                          Identifier(s) of protein(s) contained in the protein group. They are sorted by number of identified peptides in descending order.
2                                                                                                                                                  These are the IDs of those proteins that have at least half of the peptides that the leading protein has.
3 Number of peptides associated with each protein in protein group, occuring in the order as the protein IDs occur in the 'Protein IDs' column. Here distinct peptide sequences are counted. Modified forms or different charges are counted as one peptide.
```

**EDIT2:**
so playing with `readr::read_fwf()` I got a bit closer with the following code (I didn't played much attention to the start and end points of the column, just tested it).

```
writeLines(my_lines, 'test.txt')
readr::read_fwf('test.txt', 
                fwf_positions(c(1, 30, 45), c(29, 42, 300), 
                              c("Name", "Separator", "Description")),
                skip=1)
```

Problem here is, I get Gas for the empty lines within `Name` column. Since the `Description` column has multiple lines it also expects a value for `Name` but there is none.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Added an expected output. I am trying to play with `readr::read_fwf()` at the moment which could help, but struggling with the figuring out the cell widths. Ideal would be to skip `Separator` but can remove it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be achieved by using `dplyr::summarise` and `tidyr::fill`.

The approach:
Positions of texts `(i.e. Separator, Description)` in 1st row `x[1]` can be consider as guide to divide text in subsequent rows. This rule holds good as data has been extracted from a table in `pdf`. Using those position divide each row in 3 columns and prepare a data.frame. Finally, apply merge/summarise techniques to get desired result.

```
df <- rbind.data.frame(cbind(substr(x, 1, (regexpr("Separator", x[1])[1]-1)), 
           substr(x,regexpr("Separator", x[1])[1], 47), 
           substr(x, (regexpr("Description", x[1])[1]-1), nchar(x))),
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#Rename columns
names(df) <- trimws(df[1,])
#remove 1st row
df <- df[-1,]

library(tidyverse)
df %>% mutate(Name = ifelse(trimws(Name) == "", NA, trimws(Name))) %>%
     fill(Name) %>%
     group_by(Name) %>%
     summarise(Description = paste(Description, collapse=""))


# Name                 Description                                                                                                                              
# <chr>                <chr>                                                                                                                                    
# 1 Majority protein IDs These are the IDs of those proteins that have at least half ofthe peptides that the leading protein has.                                 
# 2 Peptide counts (all) Number of peptides associated with each protein in proteingroup, occuring in the order as the protein IDs occur in the'Protein IDs' colu~
# 3 Protein IDs          Identifier(s) of protein(s) contained in the protein group. Theyare sorted by number of identified peptides in descendingorder.
```

**data**

```
x <- c("     Name                             Separator Description", 
  "    Protein IDs                                Identifier(s) of protein(s) contained in the protein group. They", 
  "                                               are sorted by number of identified peptides in descending", 
  "                                               order.", "    Majority protein IDs                       These are the IDs of those proteins that have at least half of", 
  "                                               the peptides that the leading protein has.", 
  "    Peptide counts (all)                       Number of peptides associated with each protein in protein", 
  "                                               group, occuring in the order as the protein IDs occur in the", 
  "                                               'Protein IDs' column. Here distinct peptide sequences are", 
  "                                               counted. Modified forms or different charges are counted as", 
  "                                               one peptide."
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option which loops over the rows of your text:

```
df <- data.frame(name=character(), text=character())
col <- ""
content <- ""
for (row in 2:length(text)) {
    if (grepl("^\\s{1,10}[^[:space:]]", text[row])) {
        if (content != "") {
            df <- rbind(df, data.frame(col, content))
        }
        col <- gsub("^\\s*(.*?)(\\s{10,}).*", "\\1", text[row], perl=TRUE)
        content <- ""
        content <- gsub(".*\\s{10,}(.*)$", "\\1", text[row], perl=TRUE)
    } else {
        content <- paste(" ", content, gsub("^\\s+(.*)", "\\1", text[row]))
    }
}
df <- rbind(df, data.frame(col, content))

                      col
1          Protein IDs
2 Majority protein IDs
3 Peptide counts (all)

content
1 Identifier(s) of protein(s) contained in the protein group. They are sorted by number of identified peptides in descending order.
2 These are the IDs of those proteins that have at least half of the peptides that the leading protein has.
3 Number of peptides associated with each protein in protein group, occuring in the order as the protein IDs occur in the 'Protein IDs' column. Here distinct peptide sequences are counted. Modified forms or different charges are counted as one peptide.
```

### Demo